# Format Exception when converting string to short C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, short, formatexception

I'm trying to convert a `string` to a `short` in C#.
But i keep getting a format exception was unhandled error.

```
short copies = short.Parse(mainForm.quantityBox.Text);
printDocument.PrinterSettings.Copies = copies;
```

The value in the `quantityBox` is "1".

The tip that Visual Studio gave me is not really helpfull
E.G : "when converting a string to datetime parse the string to take the date before putting each variable"

Comment: What is the value inside the constant "mainForm.quantityBox.Text"

Comment: What was the textbox value at the time of exception?

Comment: show us some sample inputs..Is it in different culture,have currency symbols or separators...!

Comment: Sorry about that, edited. @saravanan

Comment: Try to ensure that there is no spaces in 1 like ' 1' or '1 ' etc.. also, what is the formatting message [+Inner exception] in this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a ToString call:

```
short copies = short.Parse(mainForm.quantityBox.Text.ToString());
```

The reason you were getting the exception is because quantityBox had a value of 1 which
is an int. short.Parse() takes a string, so by casting the contents of quantityBox.Text to
ToString(), no matter what value it is given, it will be converted to a string.

Comment: "Cannot implicitly convert type string to short"  thats what i get.

Answer (score 1):

Format exception will occur if your input text value id having "." (dot) in it. Better to replace or handle this dot(.) to avoid "`Input string was not in a correct format.`".

This will throw error:

```
short val = short.Parse("4.0");
```

This will not throw any error:

```
short val1 = short.Parse("4");
```

Answer (score 0):

The short keyword denotes an integral data type that stores values according to the size and range shown in the following [Blog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4.aspx)